# Why isn't a state variable displaying in a header but a constant is?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state: {
    title: "Graphs"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          {this.state.title}
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

But "Graphs" doesn't display when I run it. However, if I do almost the same thing but change the header to

```
<h1>
  Graphs
</h1>
```

then it displays correctly. Why doesn't the first way work?

Comment: change `state:{ ... }` to  `this.state = { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must write an equal sign `=` after `state` in your class field, not a colon `:`.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "Graphs"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "Graphs"
  };
  //or you can initialize 
  //in constructor
  //constructor(){
  // super()
  // this.state = {title: "Graphics"}
  //}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```